# Avro Error: "Unknown Union Branch" on Map field

Tags: java, json, avro

Using the `avro-tools` package from Apache I have generated a `.avsc` file from my Java class. I pointed `ReflectData` to my main class and used that to output the schema. The problem is many-fold, but fundamentally my problem is not being able to create an Avro file even though the Schema **and** the data were generated by the same class.

The code in Java is:
`Schema x = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(MessageEnvelope.class);`

So I paste the output of the above into a file and call it `msgEnvelope.avsc`

The lines of the Schema file where the error is occurring are:

```
   {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MessageEnvelope",
  "namespace": "data.decoder",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "headers",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "map",
          "values": "string"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
....
}
```

The portion of my JSON data corresponding to this part of the Schema is:

```
{"headers": {"idno":"123", "maker":"xyz"}}
```

And running `avro-tools` produces an `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch idno` The goal is to allow `headers` to contain a variable number of key-value pairs.

To produce that error I ran
`java -jar avro-tools.jar fromjson --schema-file msgEnvelope.avsc tgtJson.json`

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Furthermore, even using the Avro "random data generator" fails when I use my schema. Is the schema the issue?

`java -jar avro-tools.jar random --schema-file msgEnvelope.avsc --count 10 ./randomFromAVSC`

Answer (score 2):

I think its all because of the **json**.

Here is the example:

Java class:

```
public class MessageEnvelope {
    Map<String, String> headers;

    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }
}
```

Avro schema:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"MessageEnvelope",
    "namespace":"data.decoder",
    "fields":[{
        "name":"headers",
        "type":[
            "null",
            {"type":"map","values":"string"}
        ],
        "default":null
    }]
}
```

Json data:

```
{
    "headers":{
        "map":{
            "maker":"xyz",
            "idno":"123"
        }
    }
}
```

I call `java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar fromjson --schema-file msgEnvelope.avsc msgEnvelope.json` just as you did and don't see any exceptions.

May be you should try same json that I've used?

Comment: Here's the explanation why using "map" as a key inside the "headers" works - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201412.mbox/%3CCALEq1Z-sKNT-fBpMhAa%3DGTjLq5wuKf5mAuvLYos4Ba17hUi%2Bfw%40mail.gmail.com%3E